# How to mock object which create within the test method?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I have `ContextListener` which inject in `ServletContext` object for work with database. And this `DBJoint` object create in method which test:

```
@WebListener
public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {

        final ServletContext servletContext =
                servletContextEvent.getServletContext();

        final DBJoint joint = new DBJointHandler(
                "database_scripts", "authentication_database");

        servletContext.setAttribute("db", joint);
    }
}
```

For testing `servletContext.setAttribute("db", joint);` I need `DBJoint joint` for send in `setAttribute`.

My test:

```
@Test
public void whenThen() {

    final ServletContextEvent event = mock(ServletContextEvent.class);
    final ServletContext context = mock(ServletContext.class);
    when(event.getServletContext()).thenReturn(context);

    final ContextListener listener = new ContextListener();
    listener.contextInitialized(event);
    DBJoint joint = ..?// how to mocking this?
    verify(context).setAttribute("db", joint);
}
```

1. Testing for `servletContext.setAttribute("db", joint);` is possibly?
2. If answer "yes", how.

Thank You.

Comment: Your already know how to mock these classes. I think what you need is `org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;` where you want to "capture" the DBJoint set by the `servletContext.setAttribute("db", joint);`. Once you got the "joint" object then you can verify it. Hopes this help.

Comment: Yes, look into `org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor`

Comment: Upvoting here - just to express my appreciation for your attitude! And what I wanted to say on the other question: it was nicely written - but next time : run the exception message through a search engine before putting up a question. That can safe you a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to understand that your `servletContext` object is a mocked object and not a real object. The `joint` object is real and you don't need to mock.
You can possibly test `servletContext.setAttribute("db", joint);` using mockito verify

```
verify(servletContext).setAttribute(eq("db"), any(DBJoint.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can mock constructor by using power mock. Try this

DBJointHandler joint = new DBJointHandler("database_scripts", "authentication_database");
        try {
            PowerMockito.whenNew(DBJointHandler.class).withArguments("database_scripts", "authentication_database").thenReturn(joint);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }